# Text flipped in backBarButtonItem stack iOS

Tags: ios, swift, flip, register-transfer-level, backbarbuttonitem

I have an issue with my app. the backBarButtonItem stack flipped when the application runs in the Arabic language.
I did not use any RTL function like `CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0)` in my app and just backBarButtonItem stack flipped.
any suggest.
Thanks

[image]

default OS behavior

[image]

Comment: This is default behavior (because Arabic is right-to-left)

Comment: @aheze nop the default behavior must not be flipped!. text must be like this:
https://imgur.com/B8ziDZs

Comment: @aheze I update my question. thanks for your fast replay BTW :)

Comment: Np, that is interesting. Maybe Apple is using a transform for their apps.

Comment: i have the same problem with url content which i load it via WKWebView